# How to follow table certain column data to show the tooltip?

Tags: jquery, sql, jstree

I am created the js tree to show the folder path name. My problem how to follow database table certain column data to show the tooltip.

Below is my coding, this coding `<div id="folder_jstree" title="JTM"></div>` I just hardcode to write the title “JTM” to show the tooltip:

```html
  <?php 
   $folderData = mysqli_query($mysql_con,"SELECT * FROM folders");

   $folders_arr = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($folderData)){
      $parentid = $row['parentid'];
      if($parentid == '0') $parentid = "#";

      $selected = false;$opened = false;
      if($row['id'] == 2){
         $selected = true;$opened = true;
      }
      $folders_arr[] = array(
         "id" => $row['id'],
         "parent" => $parentid,
         "text" => $row['name'],
         "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
      );
   }

   ?>

   <!-- Initialize jsTree -->
   <div id="folder_jstree" title="JTM"></div>
   <!-- Store folder list in JSON format -->
   <textarea style="display:none;" id='txt_folderjsondata'><?= json_encode($folders_arr) ?></textarea>


<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   var folder_jsondata = JSON.parse($('#txt_folderjsondata').val());

   $('#folder_jstree').jstree({ 'core' : {
      'data' : folder_jsondata,
      'multiple': false
   } });

});

  $( function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  } );

</script>
```

Below is my database table name is `folders`, I need follow the table `name` to show the table `category`in the tooltip. For example, if I mouse pointer `MPK 400 Pengurusan Kewangan` in the JS tree, then the tooltip will show me the `categroy` name is 'JKP'. I have three types show in the table `folders` , there are `JKP`,`JTM` and 'JTM (Berhubung Kod 100-1/1/2)':

[[Table name is folders][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUy2y.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yUy2y.png)

Below is my output:
[[Output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9sw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S9sw.png)

Hope someone can guide me or show me the examples to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a tooltip on the jstree hover event. You'll have to keep the tooltip text in the node's data.

In the php code you can include the `category` column in the array

```
 $folders_arr[] = array(
    "id" => $row['id'],
    "parent" => $parentid,
    "text" => $row['name'],
    "category" => $row['category'],
    "state" => array("selected" => $selected,"opened"=>$opened) 
 );
```

In the javascript code after the jsTree initialization you could set the event handler.

```
$('#folder_jstree').bind('hover_node.jstree', function (e, data) {
    $("#" + data.node.id).attr("title", data.node.original.category);
});
```

Comment: Thanks your answer again. I think you are more professional in the JS tree. I have tried your code in the js fiddle can work https://jsfiddle.net/ason5861_cs/Lr5ow30e/11/. But if I use back my normal, put your side in my coding, cant work. I don't know which problem I get it.

Comment: I am not really sure, it  does work for with the fiddle link. I've updated it a bit to keep the event handler in the `$(document).ready` function. Here's a [link](https://jsfiddle.net/b8vgzt75/) to the new jsFiddle.

Comment: Thanks again. You save my day. Do you have whatapps contact? If next time I have a similar question, I let you know in stackoverflow

Comment: You're welcome. I don't think sharing contacts is a good idea here on SO.

Comment: I have similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61344869/according-the-table-data-number-to-sort-different-color/61345846#61345846 . But not node.js, need to show diffrerent color in the table, if you free can see my question. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to stikethrough in the js tree? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61378352/how-to-cross-out-word-if-not-active-in-the-js-tree

Comment: Hi @Stephen S. I have a quesiton similar this question coding. If you have time can help me to check it. Thanks. stackoverflow.com/questions/62669094/show-color-in-js-nodes