# According the table data number to sort different color

Tags: php, arrays

I am created the table to show the data from the database table in the page. My problem is how to according the table data prefix number to sort different color?

Below is my output:

[image: Output]

I want the prefix number follow below the number of range:

```html
Prefix number |      Color 
--------------------------
100 until 199 |      Blue
200 until 299 |      Red
300 until 399 |      Yellow
400 until 499 |      Orange
500 until 599 |      Green
```

Actually I want the output same like below the sample picture, below the sample picture is not using coding to make it, just I am used the paint software to edit and make it easy to let yours understand what I want to get the output:

[image: Output 2]

Below is my coding :

```html
<table id="" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th style='width:7%'>No</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Name</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Folder Location</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Category</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Request By</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Date Request</th>
                                
                                <!--<th class='filter_text_field'>Date Request</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Folder Name</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Category</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Folder Location</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Status_1</th>
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Email Address</th>-->
                                <th class='filter_text_field'>Status</th>
                                <?php if ($module_user_permission['edit'] == 1) { ?>
                                <th style='width:15%'>Action</th>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php
                            $sql_wtp = "select * from  filing_code_management";
                            $query_wtp = db_conn_select($sql_wtp);
                            foreach ($query_wtp as $rs_wtp) {
                                if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
                                    $active = 'Active';
                                } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
                                    $active = 'Inactive';
                                }
                                echo "<tr>";
                                echo "<td>" . (++$no) . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['name'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['folder_location'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['category'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['request_by'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['date_request'] . "</td>";
                                echo "<td>" . $active . "</td>";
                                if ($module_user_permission['edit'] == 1) {
                                    echo '<td><a href="#wtp_modal" onclick="select_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',\'wtp_content\')" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Update</a>';
                                    if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
                                            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',1)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Deactivate</a>';
                                        } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
                                            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'].$md5) . '\',0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Activate</a>';
                                        }
                                    echo '</td>';
                                }
                                echo "</tr>";
                            }
                            ?>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

**What I have tried:**

I have made a test array: $rs_wtp = array( 'name' => array( '100-1 Sometext', '233-1 Sometext', '500 Sometext' ), it can show correct in the array in the Fiddle: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9938a5e6a88de29511d22458a23a39b3a2368995. But I don't know how to combine this test code to my above coding to show the correct color according prefix number inside the table. Below is my testing array code:

```html
<?php
$rs_wtp = array(
    'name' => array(
        '100-1 Sometext',
        '233-1 Sometext',
        '500 Sometext',
        '300 Sometext',
        '300 Sometext',
        '200 Sometext',
        '110-4 Sometext',
        '150 Sometext',
        '455 Sometext',
        '500 Sometext',
        '199 Sometext'
    )  
);
$colors = array (
    1 => "blue",   //--> for all colors within the range of 100-199
    2 => "red",    //--> for all colors within the range of 200-299
    3 => "yellow", //--> for all colors within the range of 300-399
    4 => "purple", //--> for all colors within the range of 400-499
    5 => "green"   //--> for all colors within the range of 500-599
);
$stmt = 'Rules:<br>
1 => "blue"   //--> for all colors within the range of 100-199
2 => "red"    //--> for all colors within the range of 200-299
3 => "yellow" //--> for all colors within the range of 300-399
4 => "purple" //--> for all colors within the range of 400-499
5 => "green"  //--> for all colors within the range of 500-599

';


foreach($rs_wtp['name'] as $name => $valuetocheck){
    $check = $valuetocheck[0];
    $stmt .= '<div style="color:'; 
    foreach ($colors as $key => $color){            
        if($check == $key){
            $stmt .= $color;
        }
    }$stmt .= ';">'.$valuetocheck.'</div>';
}
echo $stmt;
```

Hope someone can guide me or give me some ideas to make it work to show the color according the prefix number in the table page. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping, analyze the number with the mappings of a range and use the colorname as a CSS class.

Default is black, if none was found.

```php
// create a map with FROM, TO and COLOR
$colorRanges = [
    [100, 199, 'blue'],
    [200, 299, 'red'],
    [300, 399, 'yellow'],
    [400, 499, 'orange'],
    [500, 599, 'green'],
];

$rs_wtp = array(
    'name' => array(
        '100-1 Sometext',
        '233-1 Sometext',
        '500 Sometext',
        '300 Sometext',
        '300 Sometext',
        '200 Sometext',
        '110-4 Sometext',
        '150 Sometext',
        '455 Sometext',
        '500 Sometext',
        '199 Sometext'
    )
);

foreach ($rs_wtp['name'] as $text) {

    // default
    $colorClass = 'black';

    // check for the number at the beginning of the line
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $text, $matches)) {
        $id = $matches[1];
        // search for the number in the mapping array
        foreach ($colorRanges as $range) {
            list($from, $to, $className) = $range;
            if ($id >= $from && $id <= $to) {
                $colorClass = $className;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // colored output
    echo "<div class='$colorClass'>$text</div>", PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output

```html
<div class='blue'>100-1 Sometext</div>
<div class='red'>233-1 Sometext</div>
<div class='green'>500 Sometext</div>
<div class='yellow'>300 Sometext</div>
<div class='yellow'>300 Sometext</div>
<div class='red'>200 Sometext</div>
<div class='blue'>110-4 Sometext</div>
<div class='blue'>150 Sometext</div>
<div class='orange'>455 Sometext</div>
<div class='green'>500 Sometext</div>
<div class='blue'>199 Sometext</div>
```

### Update

from your comment how to implement to your code. Just place after `<tbody><?php`.

```php
<?php
$colorRanges = [
    [100, 199, 'blue'],
    [200, 299, 'red'],
    [300, 399, 'yellow'],
    [400, 499, 'orange'],
    [500, 599, 'green'],
];

$sql_wtp = "select * from  filing_code_management";
$query_wtp = db_conn_select($sql_wtp);
foreach ($query_wtp as $rs_wtp) {
    if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
        $active = 'Active';
    } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
        $active = 'Inactive';
    }

    $colorClass = 'black';

    // check for the number at the beginning of the line
    if (preg_match('/^(\d+)/', $rs_wtp['name'], $matches)) {
        $id = $matches[1];
        // search for the number in the mapping array
        foreach ($colorRanges as $range) {
            list($from, $to, $className) = $range;
            if ($id >= $from && $id <= $to) {
                $colorClass = $className;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . (++$no) . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='color:{$colorClass}'>" . $rs_wtp['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td style='color:{$colorClass}'>" . $rs_wtp['folder_location'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['category'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['request_by'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $rs_wtp['date_request'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $active . "</td>";
    if ($module_user_permission['edit'] == 1) {
        echo '<td><a href="#wtp_modal" onclick="select_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'] . $md5) . '\',\'wtp_content\')" data-toggle="modal" data-original-title="Help" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Update</a>';
        if ($rs_wtp['status'] == 1) {
            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'] . $md5) . '\',1)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Deactivate</a>';
        } elseif ($rs_wtp['status'] == 0) {
            echo '<a onclick="delete_(\'' . md5($rs_wtp['id'] . $md5) . '\',0)" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-color-format="hex">Activate</a>';
        }
        echo '</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thansk for your answer. May I know how to put code combine with my table code?